# ggplot: How to change the visualisation of an RFE plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rfe

I have an RFE output,`rfe2014`, saved from another R session:

```
Variables Accuracy  Kappa AccuracySD KappaSD Selected
    15   0.7534 0.7107    0.04265 0.04996         
    25   0.7808 0.7429    0.03510 0.04120         
    35   0.7905 0.7542    0.03460 0.04060         
    45   0.7935 0.7578    0.03113 0.03661         
    50   0.7982 0.7633    0.03358 0.03945         
    60   0.8014 0.7670    0.03021 0.03546        *
    70   0.8009 0.7664    0.03127 0.03673         
    80   0.7997 0.7650    0.03099 0.03640         
    90   0.7997 0.7650    0.03198 0.03753         
   105   0.8002 0.7656    0.03135 0.03686         
   109   0.8010 0.7665    0.03188 0.03749
```

Plotting via ggplot works well:

```
ggplot(data = rfe2014, mapping = NULL, metric = "Accuracy",
  output = "layered", environment = NULL)
```

[RFE plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUFoJ.png)

How can I change how the blue dot is depicted (which indicates the optimal amount of variables) regarding size and color? `geom_point()` affects all points. I only want to change the >master point<.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351608/color-one-point-and-add-an-annotation-in-ggplot2

Comment: You may filter the row with the value of interest and add another +geom_point() where you add  data source in it to the filtered data frame.