# How to plot a single point onto a ggplot graph in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a single point to a curve (line equation in terms of x) in ggplot in r along an x axis from 0 to 35. Whenever I try to plot a point I run into the problem where I get an error with aes()... how do I fix this? All I need is a singular point labeled "point" that is blue and at those coordinates.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,35)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun=function(x)10^(-0.05841*x)+10^7.2241, geom="line") +
 geom_point() +
annotate("point", x = 23, y = 39000, colour = "blue")
```

And when I run this I get this error:

```
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (2): y
```

thanks!

Comment: What's do you intend the `geom_point` call to do? If you take it out, this runs.

Comment: Duplicate of [Color one point and add an annotation in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351608/color-one-point-and-add-an-annotation-in-ggplot2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I try to run your code I get a different error:

`Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y`

So it's easily solved:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,35)), aes(x)) +
     stat_function(fun=function(x)10^(-0.05841*x)+10^7.2241, geom="line") +
     geom_point(aes(x = 23, y = 39000), color = "blue", size = 2) +
     geom_text(data = data.frame(x = 23, y = 39000), aes(x, y, label = "point"))
```

Notice that I changed your `annotate` with `geom_text`, just in case you want to annotate not one, but several and do it from a `data.frame`

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps like this?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,35)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun=function(x)10^(-0.05841*x)+10^7.2241, geom="line") +
  annotate("point", x = 23, y = 39000, colour = "blue") +
  annotate("text", x = 23, y = 39000, label = "point", colour = "blue", vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]