# How to label 1 point in R scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to label state with unusually high murder rate using `geom_text()`
Find the murder rate per millions. get the one with the highest.

```
ggplot(data = murders, aes(x = population/10^6, y = total)) + geom_point(aes(color = region)) + 
  xlab("population in millions") + ylab("murders") + ggtitle("US murders by state") + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) + geom_text(aes(label = abb))
```

This labels all points in the scatter plot. How would I label just one for the state with an unusually high murder rate?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Color one point and add an annotation in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351608/color-one-point-and-add-an-annotation-in-ggplot2)?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply calculate the murder rate and create a label column that just contains the `abb` for the state/district with the highest rate.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs) # for murders dataset

murders %>% 
  mutate(murder_per_capita = total/population) %>% 
  mutate(label = if_else(murder_per_capita == max(murder_per_capita), abb, NA_character_)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = population/10^6, y = total)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = region)) + 
  xlab("population in millions") + 
  ylab("murders") + 
  ggtitle("US murders by state") + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

However, given the roughly log-normal distribution of these variables, I think it would make more sense to show this plot with log-transformed axes. It both helps you satisfy the [basic assumptions of linear regression](https://www.statology.org/linear-regression-assumptions/)  and also makes it more clear how much of an outlier DC is:

```r
qqnorm(log10(murders$population), main = "Log-normality of population")
```

[image]

```r
qqnorm(log10(murders$total), main = "Log-normality of murders")
```

[image]

```r
murders %>% 
  mutate(murder_per_capita = total/population) %>% 
  mutate(label = if_else(murder_per_capita == max(murder_per_capita), abb, NA_character_)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = population/10^6, y = total)) + 
  scale_x_log10("population in millions") +
  scale_y_log10("murders") +
  geom_point(aes(color = region)) + 
  ggtitle("US murders by state") + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>